# Generate XML documentation for private members

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to generate XML documentation for private members? Be default it only generates it for public members, which is correct for published code but not for code only used within a company.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/).

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to write the xml documentation together with code. It doesn't take much time and also I have found that this approach helps me organize my code structure better.

Comment: Right: tool generated XML documentation is almost never useful. Or do you think a method Add(Product p) with an XML documentation comment of "Adds the product" (and <param name="p">Product to add</param>) is worth its bytes...?

Comment: (Ehh... the documentation comments, not the method itself. Duh!)

Comment: For someone who has no idea of the method the stupid comment will make it obvious there is nothing special ;). But your point is right, sometimes comments are just waste of time and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

For Sandcastle the answer is given here: [Sandcastle not generating private methods docs (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104078/sandcastle-not-generating-private-methods-docs-c)

(Turn on DocumentPrivates in Sandcastle.)