# Sandcastle not generating private methods docs (C#)

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm using the latest version of Sandcastle to generate documentation. I have a couple of public Instance classes with public and private methods and fields. The public methods are generated in the final docs output by Sandcastle but no other members are generated. Under Visibility, I have everything checked so I expect that everything should be generated in the documentation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to generate API docs for private methods? They are implementation details and so should not appear in any form of documentation beyond the code itself.

Comment: Because this is for internal doc's where people want to know what's going on in the guts.

Comment: Then they should read the code. Expecting them to look at comments away from the code to work out what the code does is madness.

Comment: So why does Sandcastle have a setting that says Show Private members?

Comment: A very good question. Why, indeed?

Comment: As in our case, not all people know how to read code, they just want to get a high level, for whatever purposes.

Comment: I refer you back to my first comment. Further, if they can't read code, what benefit do you feel they'll get from reading any sort of API docs?

Answer (score 2):

As from official FAQ from Eric Woodruff(developer of Sandcastle Help File Builder)

> Classes need to be declared public in your code, you need to enable
>   the DocumentPrivates and/or DocumentInternals project property so that
>   Sandcastle documents the internal/private members, or you need to
>   include at least one assembly and at least one namespace to document.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have, public classes and I have enabled show privates :)